# Installing Ruby - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know anything about the stuff that you write here :) I tried to search for answers online, as I usually do, but unfortunately, couldn't find anything specific.

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails, according to a description from here [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning)

I have installed Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Could you tell me what have I done wrong? Or how can I fix it to install it properly?

when I check ruby version it shows me:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86-64-linux-gnu]
```

However an error appears:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0./gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170726-93-g151dm.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nio4r-2.1.0/gem_make.out
```

I have also done:

```
apt-get install make
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

And now something different appeared:

```
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0./gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170726-530-13b2fuh.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h...***extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration option.
```

The rest of the code can be found in the file - too much things to write by hand. :) [Ruby 2- command line pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Xob.jpg)

Please help!! I want to learn Ruby :) :)

Plus, is there a way to copy command line and to paste it somehow or do I have to put it here letter by letter? :)

Comment: I recommend you to not use Windows with ruby/rails. Try a Linux virtual machine

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential patch`

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev`

Hope it will help!

I also recommend you to install [RVM](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm).

Then run `rvm install your_version` to install an essential ruby version. You can choose any version you need. For instance `rvm install 2.4.1`

After those steps, run following commands:

`gem install bundler`

`gem install rails`

Comment: Thank you!! It went a lot better but now when I try 'rails new hello_app', I got info: run bundle install --local
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
run bundle exec spring binstub -all
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)

Comment: @AdaSz I've edited an answer. If you'll have new questions, feel free to ask

Answer (score 3):

You need ruby development files to build (& install) native extensions 
**sudo apt-get install ruby-dev**